# NTP polling values does not change

Tags: time, polling, ntp

I am processing (tcpdump) logs from a NTP server. The logs were collected for a day. I am seeing four different types of polling intervals for the clients in these NTP server logs as follows:

1. Increasing polling interval values: polling values are increasing and at some point reaches a set of constant values.
2. Decreasing polling interval values: similar to #1 (but the opposite case)
3. Constant polling interval values: apparently, I see a lot of these and for such clients the polling values are *just* constant.
4. Varying polling interval values: in this case, we are seeing a lot of variations.

I can hypothesize that #1, #2 and #4 are NTP clock sync. algorithm specific. But what about #3? Is it because of configuration? That is, is it the default configuration for many clients? I am looking for a possible explanation for this. Also, any pointers in the NTP doc. would be great too.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that ntp traffic from one IPv4 address is produced by one and only ntp client. I do not think this is a safe assumption to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ntp docs](http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.6p5/confopt.html):

`minpoll minpoll
maxpoll maxpoll`

> These options specify the minimum and maximum poll intervals for NTP
>   messages, in seconds as a power of two. The maximum poll interval
>   defaults to 10 (1024 s), but can be increased by the maxpoll option to
>   an upper limit of 17 (36 h). The minimum poll interval defaults to 6
>   (64 s), but can be decreased by the minpoll option to a lower limit of
>   3 (8 s).

It's *not* normal for clients to have a fixed interval (The default config does not set that) but I for example use fixed intervals on certain servers/production machines.

Also keep in mind the comment @dfc made.